# Setup default row in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with setup default row in TableView. I just wanna always pick first element from dataSource. I tried a few solutions with "selectRow" and other but no one of them work.

Here's my code below:

```swift
class HomeVC: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var btnSelectCountry: UIButton!

    let transparentView = UIView()
    let tableView = UITableView()

    var selectedButton = UIButton()
    var dataSource = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
       tableView.register(CellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell") 
let index = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.selectRow(at: index as IndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)

    }

    func addTransparentView(frames: CGRect){
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        transparentView.frame = window?.frame ?? self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(transparentView)

        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0 )
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
        tableView.reloadData()

        let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTransparentView))
        transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
        transparentView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height + 5, width: frames.width, height: CGFloat(self.dataSource.count * 50))

        }, completion: nil)   
    }
}

extension HomeVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedButton.setTitle(dataSource[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        removeTransparentView()
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you should just use dataSource.first or dataSource[0] …?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `viewDidLoad()` with this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(CellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: index)

}
```

This will automatically trigger the `didSelectRow` method but you need to populate your dataSource before this or the application will crash.

You can try adding this for example in `viewWillAppear()`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    dataSource = ["Your", "Data"]
}
```

Comment: It's only works after I clicked in tableView(button). When I tried your solutions to initialize tableView with "didSelectRowAt" command then always print "Nil".

Comment: Could you show me an example of what you are trying to achieve?